# I don't know how to do this query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

[image: Table SQL]

I need to get the following result, for example:

> Usuario: 4 - idRonda: 2 - puntaje: 80 - idRonda: 3 - puntaje: 85. (1
> Row per user)

And not this:

> User: 4 - idRonda: 2 - puntaje: 80
>
> User 4: - idROnda: 3 - puntaje: 85

Thanks for your help

Comment: Use GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT function.

Comment: Problems of data display are best resolved in a presentation layer / application level code, if that's available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Select t.idUsuario ,t.idRonda,t.punjtae,s.idRonda,s.punjtae 
from mytable s INNER JOIN mytable t
ON s.idUsuario = t.idUsuario;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT idUsuario, GROUP_CONCAT(idRonda) AS 'idRonda', GROUP_CONCAT(punjtae) AS 'punjtae'
FROM your_table
GROUP BY idUsuario
```

Comment: I didn´t know "GROUP_CONCAT", we just need to add GROUP BY...

SELECT idUsuario, GROUP_CONCAT(idRonda) AS 'idRonda', GROUP_CONCAT(punjtae) AS 'punjtae'
FROM your_table GROUP BY idUsuario

Thanks